# Positioning inline labels containing input element dynamically sized into a form

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a form with some input tags into label tags. Inputs are displayed below labels. I want the inputs/labels to be dynamically resized based on the width of the form. The problem is that the last input-label go into the line below if I tell labels to occupy the 100% of the width of the form.

Here's an example of my code:

```
    <form action="">
        <label>Label1:<br>
            <input type="text"></label>
        <label>Label2:<br>
            <input type="text"></label>
    </form>
```

And here is some of the CSS:

```
    form {
        width:60%;
        border:1px solid indigo;
    }
    label{
        display:inline-block;
        margin:0;
        width:50%;
    }
    input{
        width:100%
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whitespace between your label elements is taking up space, preventing the elements from appearing side by side.  Comment it out, and it works:

http://tinker.io/5e4b9

```
<form action="">
    <label>Label1:<br>
        <input type="text"></label><!--
    --><label>Label2:<br>
        <input type="text"></label>
</form>
```

Comment: Good catch, the extra white space causes the problem.  However, the extra comment looks a bit fragile.

Comment: If you're uncomfortable with the comment (though there's nothing fragile about it), there are other ways to effectively remove the space.  Instead of setting the elements to inline-block, you could either float them or set them to table-cell:  http://tinker.io/5e4b9/1.

Comment: Actually, there is a problem (not yours) with the 100% width on the input field, which causes it to overflow out to the right and past the right border.  Personally, I would have set the width for the <label> element to 49% and done with it.

Comment: It's because the input elements have padding on them, so they're 100% wide + the padding.  Adjusting the box-sizing fixes it up:  http://tinker.io/5e4b9/2

Comment: I added -moz-box-sizing to see it in Firefox.  Works nicely.  +1